# Missing available space in device block (size != used + available)

Tags: linux, lvm

So, there is this device block which has 654G of total size, of those 579G are
being used, but only 42 is Avail (it should be 65G available!)

```bash
$ df -h /dev/mapper/cryptdata
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/mapper/cryptdata  654G  579G   42G  94% /data
$ du -sh /data
579G    /data
```

What is wrong here? I suspect maybe it has to do with Filesystem integrity or
LVM (Logical Volume Manager).

What I need is to correct this error so it should have 65G available, but I
don't know how.

Comment: 95% of 654 ≈ 579+42.

Comment: yes, it does answer @muru